# How to access nested attributed in spark sql

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to access nested attributes of json file stored in a table (parquet). I can access all the records of the table by
select * from test;

However, I am not able to access nested attributes by writing query as :
val tab= sqlContext.sql("select text, user.screen_name from test LIMIT 1")

Schema is as below:

```
|-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- truncated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- is_translator: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Below is my code :

```
import scala.tools.nsc.doc.model.Object
import scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Main
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


object SimpleSparkSQL {
 def main(args:Array[String]) {
val path = args(0);
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple         Application").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g") 
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data = sc.textFile(path)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlc.read.json(data)

df.select("text",    "user.screen_name").write.format("parquet").save("staging.parquet")
val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("staging.parquet")
parquetFile.registerTempTable("test")
//= 514621627494322176  where user.screen_name='abyschan'
val tab= sqlContext.sql("select * from test LIMIT 1")
df.printSchema()
tab.collect().foreach{println}

  } 

}
```

NOTE: Select * from test works fine but when I try to select user.screen_name (nested attribute) I am getting the error of "Cannot resolve user.screen_name "

Comment: You should probably include in your question what behaviour you're expecting and what you're actually getting. Have a look here for pointers on asking questions [ask}

Answer (score 1):

According to your schema, you should be selecting `text.user.screen_name`.

Answer (score 1):

I used below query and it worked.

val tab= sqlContext.sql("select screen_name, count(text) from test group by screen_name DESC LIMIT 1"

It worked using just screen_name but did not require to use user.screen_name. Since I have flattened json data in a parquet table hence it no more requires '.' to access nested attributes of json.

Comment: Correct. since you are creating table , you dont have to use user.screen_name but just screen_name would work.